# Regex for detecting italic markdown designators

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, markdown

I have the following test string:

```
const string = '*Foo* **Foo** ***Foo*** ** ****';
```

And I want to use `RegExp` to extract the following matches with a `named capturing group` called `content`:

```
STRING:   *Foo* **Foo** ***Foo*** ** ****
MATCH:    ^^^^^           ^^^^^   ^^
CONTENT:   ^^^             ^^^
```

---

It would be also great to match whitespaces as well.

```
const string = '* Foo * ** Foo ** *** Foo *** * * ** **';
```

This shall result in the following matches:

```
STRING:   * Foo * ** Foo ** *** Foo *** * * ** **
MATCH:    ^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^   ^^^
CONTENT:    ^^^                 ^^^      ^
```

---

I've tried several regex patterns, but I don't seem to get the correct pattern for `\*` but not `\*{2}`.

Here is one of them:

```
/(?!\*\*\s*?.+?\s*?\*\*)\*\s*?(?<content>.+?)\s*?\*/g
```

This is the result: https://regex101.com/r/OqSMuO/3

How can I get it to work? Thanks!

Comment: Please leave me a comment, why you have downvoted. I described my issue. I also added an example of how my `RegExp` looks like.

Comment: someone probably agreed to the fact that markdown should never be parsed with regex. similar to html or xml but with a token scanner instead.

Comment: @GottZ I am not trying to build a parser really. I am just trying to build an editor that can remove designators when found inside a selection. I've got pretty far with it and this currently is a hard thing to come by.

Comment: While I agree that regular expressions aren't the place for as complex languages as markdown, looking at the problem in the simple context you provided, I believe this regex would work: `\*\s*?(.*?)\s*?\*`.  However, looking at the problem as a whole, you should _really_ consider something a little more [suited for markdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown).

Comment: If you want to include the spaces, just wrap them in parentheses, too.  Let me know if this helps and I'll write an actual answer.  I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, though.

Comment: Named capturing groups are not available in JS. What are you trying to do? What are the requirements?

Comment: I will post a new question soon which will be simpler. I've gone overboard here obviously.

Comment: New simpler question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50378996/1171404

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but maybe it will give you a boost:

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))(?:\*\s*(?<content1>[^*]+)\s*?\*|\*{3}\s*(?<content3>[^*]*)\s*\*{3})(?:$|(?=\s))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eJiE7S/2)

Comment: This looks promising. The second match still contains `***` as prefix and `***` as suffix instead of just one `*` each.

Comment: I updated it a bit.  It's still not perfect, but closer

Comment: You should warn that named capturing groups are not available in JS. Chrome is the only one browser with its support.

Comment: I will post a new question soon which will be simpler. I've gone overboard here obviously.

Comment: @SebastianKrogull You have not gone overboard, you did not actually describe the *rules*, and your two examples are not quite enough to visualize your requirements. Those examples are mutually exclusive.