# Match single character but not multiple

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a RegExp like this one:

```
/(?!xx)x.+?(?!xx)x/g
```

There are three example strings that I test. I marked the expected matches with `^`.

#### Expectations:

Should match `0-5`:

```
x...x
^^^^^
```

Should not match

```
xx...xx
```

Should match `2-7`:

```
xxx...xxx
  ^^^^^
```

Should match `3-8`:

```
xxxx...xxxx
   ^^^^^
```

#### My problem:

I have not found a way to match `x` without matching `xx` and I am running out of ideas to try. Please help me. 
This is the current result: https://regex101.com/r/OqSMuO/5

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want the second one to not match, but the third one to match? What would the expected behavior be for xxxx...xxxx?

Comment: Will update the question. Do you need more information @AnilRedshift?

Comment: My understanding is that you want all instances of x...x to match except when it's exactly xx...xx. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you mean to use `\.` instead of `.`, the wildcard? `.` will also match `x`.

Comment: This is correct. The characters inside the `x`es does not matter except more than one matches would be produced @AnilRedshift.

Comment: @Jacob The wildcard is intentional. But it should not match `x`. Good point!

Comment: Use `[^x]` instead of `.` maybe.

Comment: Try [`(?:^|[^x])(?:x{2,})?(x[^x]+x)(?!x(?!x))`](https://regex101.com/r/UUiuRj/2), grab the value in Group 1.

Comment: As jacob said use `x[^x]+x`. I don't see any thing more with your requirements.

Comment: @revo It would still match stuff like that: `xx...xx` which i do not want: https://regex101.com/r/MsrClF/1

Comment: @SebastianKrogull Did you try my suggestion? Do you need to only match these strings as standalone strings or in longer texts?

Comment: If you code for Chrome/ECMAScript 2018 only, check https://regex101.com/r/uKAmBJ/1

Comment: Looks like I am getting near a solution: https://regex101.com/r/MsrClF/5

Answer (score 1):

I think this matches your intent.

```
^(?:(x[^x]{3}x)|x{2,}(x[^x]{3}x)x{2,})$
```

It is split into two parts, OR'd together:

`(x[^x]{3}x)` matches the case of exactly `x...x`

and `x{2,}(x[^x]{3}x)x{2,}` matches `xxx...xxx` but not `xx...xx`

Note: This does not help you for unbalanced matches. E.g. for example `(xxx...xxxx)` would still match the regex. However, as far as I know, you can't solve that problem with just a regex. You would need a stack to do so.

Comment: I think this comes near my expectations: Could you take a look at this: `^(?:(x[^x]+?x)|x{2,}(x[^x]+?x)x{2,})$` ?

Comment: Also it would be great if there would only be one group inside the match.

Answer (score 0):

If the leading number of times x should be the same as the trailing number times you could use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to capturing group 1:

[`^(x*)(x[^x]+x)(\1)$`](https://regex101.com/r/YikRir/1)

From the beginning of the string `^`, capture in group 1 zero or more times an `x`. Then capture in group 2 an `x`, one or more times not an `x` followed by an x `(x[^x]+x)` using a negated character class. This group will contain your match.

At the end use a backreference `\1` to match the same again as in group 1 and assert the end of the string `$`.

```js
const strings = [
  "x...x",
  "xx...x",
  "xx...",
  "xx..xx",
  "xxx...xxx",
  "xxxx...xxxx",
];
let pattern = /^(x*)(x[^x]+x)(\1)$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  let res = s.match(pattern);
  if (res) {
    console.log(s + " --> " + s.match(pattern)[2]);
  } else {
    console.log(s + " --> no match.");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This captures every `x...x` except the one starting with two "xx" (`xx...xx`).

```
(?:^x{0}|x{2,})(x...x)
```